# Gtk IconView select multiple without Ctrl?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

Is it possible to make Gtk IconView (in pygtk) allow selection of multiple icons without the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key being pressed?

I basically want the behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> being held down even when it is not held down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding this kind of behaviour might confuse users. But if you really want to, there are two possibilities that I can see:

Either make the `IconView` believe <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is always pressed:

```
def force_ctrl(iv, ev): ev.state |= gtk.gdk.CONTROL_MASK
iconview.connect('key-press-event', force_ctrl)
iconview.connect('button-press-event', force_ctrl)
```

Or you could try implementing the selection behaviour yourself, something like:

```
def clicked(iv, ev):
    p = iv.get_path_at_pos(int(ev.x), int(ev.y))
    if not p is None:
        if iv.path_is_selected(p):
            iv.unselect_path(p)
        else:
            iv.select_path(p)
    return True # make the IconView ignore this click
iconview.connect('button-press-event', clicked)
```